Create pipleine in Azure devops by rest API failed - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: repositoryName
I am tring to create Azure devops (tfs) Pipeline by rets API as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
Request url:  https://tfs.xxx/tfs/Projects/xxx/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview
Request body:
{   
    "folder": null,   
    "name": "pipeline-made-by-api",   
    "configuration": {     
        "type": "yaml",     
        "path": "build.yaml",     
        "repository": {       
            "id": "xxx",       
            "name": "xxx-repo",       
            "type": "azureReposGit"     
        }   
    } 
}

I got error 400 with response:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: repositoryName","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

I don't see any parameter called repositoryName in the documentation.
What am i missing?
Thanks!
EDITED:
I tried by shell script too:
This is the script (copied from  @wade zhou - MSFT answer)

This is the results:


Modify your request by passing name repository": {       "id": "guid-of-repo-id",       "name": "my-repo",       "type": "azureReposGit"     }

The body must be {   "folder": null,   "name": "pipeline-made-by-api",   "configuration": {     "type": "yaml",     "path": "/azure-pipelines.yml",     "repository": {       "id": "guid-of-repo-id",       "name": "my-repo",       "type": "azureReposGit"     }   } }

Tried. same error.

Can you edit the question by the request body you are trying now?

Edited. request body is changed.

OR try { "configuration": {     "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",     "repository": {         "id": "YourRepoGUID",         "type": "azureReposGit"     },     "type": "yaml" }, "name": "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_HERE"

I don't see any change betwean the link you attached and my request body.

and in your last suggest - you remove the name from repository object. right? how will this help?

@ostr, as you are using onm-prem tfs, please fix the url, and follow the request body in my reply below for a check, thanks

The shell script sample:
PAT="PAT"
ORG_URL="http://vm0/DefaultCollection"
PROJECT="Project2"
PIPELINE_NAME="test2"
YAML_PATH="build.yml"
repositoryId="3axx-1xx8-4xxb-8xx6-800xx4594e"
repositoryName="Project2"


curl -u ":$PAT" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "configuration": {
      
      "type": "yaml",
      "path": "'"$YAML_PATH"'",
      "repository": {
        "id": "'"$repositoryId"'",
        "name":"'"$repositoryName"'",
        "type": "azureReposGit"
      }
    },
    "name": "'"$PIPELINE_NAME"'",
    "folder": "testfolder"

  }' \
  "$ORG_URL/$PROJECT/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview"


Edit:
For the error Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: repositoryName", as per your ADO version 2020(Dev18.M170.7), there is a bug reported before in community link, it's fixed in 2020.1. Please install server patch to upgrade, then try again.

With no "Projects" in the URL i get 404... I have to understand the differences betwean my request and your becouse i need the script in shell, not PS. Thanks!

@ostr, i edit the reply with shell script, thanks.

Thank you for the shell example!! i tried and same result :-( i will try the azure CLI and update here. Thanks!

@ostr, the azure CLI only supports DevOps cloud service, it doesn't support on-prem ADO server(TFS), i have removed it in the reply. If you encounter error with the shell script sample, can you share some shell log in the description? Is the rest api url correct now?

@ostr, you can copy my shell script, and replace the parameters to have a check. let me know if you have any queries.

tried, same result. i edit the question with print screens

@ostr, this is inline script not sh file. Please copy the content, update the parameters and then pasted into the shell window for a check, thanks.

exactlly same response in sell script and in inline: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: repositoryName","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

@ostr, may i know what's your TFS version? and is the repo git type or TFVC type? Please access your TFS collection, open a new browser tab, paste https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.0 (replace parameters, it used rest api Repositories - List), are you able to find the target repository id and repository name? Compare the value with your shell script, is it correct?

My tfs version (from https://tfs.XXXX/tfs/Projects/XXX/_home/about) is Version Dev18.M170.7. The repo is git repo. I verified again the repository name and id by the repository API. they are correct.

@ostr, it should be a bug which exists on your ADO2020(Dev18.M170.7), please install patch to upgrade your ADO server, then try again. Please refer to the community link for more details.

Thank you very match!! I dont sure my campeny will update the tfs version right now, but  it is helpful to know it is not my bug :-)

pleass add this comment as answer, so i will sign it as a solution

@ostr, i have edited the answer with the info, thank you.

Pipeline yaml be located in specific repository, so you must provide the repository id. A simple way to get your repository id:
azureDevopsRepositoryGet.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$OrganizationName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ProjectName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$RepositoryName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [hashtable]$Headers
)

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}?api-version=7.0" -f $OrganizationName, $ProjectName, $RepositoryName

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Get' -Headers $headers

return $response

Then you can pass the repository id into
azureDevopsPipelineCreate.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$OrganizationName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ProjectName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$PipelineName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$PipelineYamlFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$RepositoryId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$RepositoryName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$BranchName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [hashtable]$Headers
)

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=7.0" -f $OrganizationName, $ProjectName

$body = @{
    folder        = "\"
    name          = $PipelineName
    configuration = @{
        type       = "yaml"
        path       = $PipelineYamlFile
        repository = @{
            id   = $RepositoryId
            name = $RepositoryName
            type = "azureReposGit"
        }
    }
}| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Post' -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -Body $body

return $response

How to get header
azureDevopsHearderGet.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$PersonalAccessToken
)

$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f $UserName, $PersonalAccessToken)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth) }
return $headers


I provided repository id. the XXX is just place holder, in my trings it is populate with real repository id. i don't see how is your request body is different then mine. am I miss something?

your folder provided null ? is this wrong?

I tried both - null and existing folder. same result

I think you can run 'get repository' rest api and get the response of a exisitng pipeline, and check what is in different. If you do not want debug hard, just copy and paste my code, it has been used for a long time, always works well.

This is what i did. i need my script in shell. so, to copy your power shel is not helping me. Thanks!
